# deleting data from mat-table but data not refreshing automatically

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table that populates data from Postgres.
I am able to populate the data. I have written a method to delete data from my mat-table. but when I click on the delete button then all data goes off from the screen and the data that I clicked remains. After I refresh the page manually and then I see that the data that I deleted is deleted and rest are there.

Example:

I have a table with the below row:

```
Roll    name     Action
1        rtr       Del
2        were      Del   <----- I am clicking delete here
3        kjk       Del
4        hgt       Del
```

I get the below table when I click the `Del` for `Roll 2`.

```
Roll    name     Action
2       were      Del            //all data is not visible but only the data that I clicked for delete is visible
```

Now I refresh the page manually and I get the updated table:

```
Roll    name     Action
1        rtr       Del
3        kjk       Del
4        hgt       Del
```

**is there any way that I can get the updated fields without refreshing???**

My codes so far:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- title Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="textareaValue">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.textareaValue}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>


  <!-- difficulty Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="difficulty">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Difficulty  </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.difficulty}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Action </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary"> <mat-icon (click)="deleteQuestionSet(element)">Delete</mat-icon></button>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

**My .ts file :**

```
  deleteQuestionSet(row)
  {
    this.dataSource.data = <QuestionSetInterface>this.dataSource.data.filter(i => i == row) ;
    this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8080/mylearning/deletequestionSet',this.dataSource.data[0],{ responseType: "text" })
  .subscribe(response => console.log(response) );
   this.isDeleted =true;
}
```

Please assist me.

**Is there any way that I can get the updated fields without refreshing???**

Comment: You can manually remove the element from array or fetch the data again after completion of deleting. Fetching again is most preferred way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to Create a function for get Data you delete !

**.ts**

```
deleteQuestionSet(row)
  {
    this.dataSource.data = <QuestionSetInterface>this.dataSource.data.filter(i => i == row) ;
    this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8080/mylearning/deletequestionSet',this.dataSource.data[0],{ responseType: "text" })
     .subscribe(response => 
   console.log(response) );
   this.getData();          <------- make a function for get Updated Data
   this.isDeleted =true;
}

getData() {
     this.httpClient.post('API FOR GET DATA'{ responseType: "text" })
     .subscribe(response => 
       console.log(response) );
}
```

Comment: When I delete a particular row, then that row stays in the screen, and the rest goes. When I refresh the screen manually the updated table is then visible.

Comment: I tried, but this is not working, It particular row for which I clicked the delete stays and rest vanish from the screen. Now when I refresh the screen manually then the updated table is visible.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your deletion function. You are updating the function to show only the deleted row. You need something like:
Pass the index from your html

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i = index">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary"> <mat-icon (click)="deleteQuestionSet(element,i)">Delete</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-cell>
```

Update the delete function

```
  deleteQuestionSet(row,i)
  {
     this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8080/mylearning/deletequestionSet',this.dataSource.data[i],{ responseType: "text" })
       .subscribe(response => console.log(response) );
     this.dataSource.data.splice(i,1); // remove the row at position i
     this.isDeleted =true;
    }
```

Comment: Now, data is not even deleting :(

Comment: Maybe indexOf doesnt work in ur case. can u pass the index from the html?  check if you are getting the correct index at i and also dont forget to change this.dataSource.data[0] to this.dataSource.data[i] in the post method

Comment: TypeError: this.dataSource.splice is not a function :(

Comment: Sorry this.dataSource.data.splice(). Updated the answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to do a reload from the backend (only on error*), but the main problem is that your filter is set to only return the deleted row. You need to invert that to `.filter(i => i != row)`. Filter returns those values that match the condition, not removes them.

*You can also implement some behavioursubject/observable structure (in a service) in your frontend and perform a reload from the server behind the scenes. Using trackby on the mat-table too. Going that way you would not directly subscribe to the request in the component, but instead to the observable in the service.